# How to set route to controller which updates specify model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, routes

I have `SettingsController` which allows me manage `User`'s settings.

```
class Api::V1::SettingsController < Api::V1::BaseController  

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.settings = JSON.parse(params[:settings])

    authorize! :edit, @user

    if @user.save
      render status: :ok
    else
      render status: :bad_request
    end
  end

end
```

And route for that

```
resources :settings, only: [:show, :update]
```

Settings is a text field with: `serialize :settings, HashWithIndifferentAccess`

So I am sending `PUT` request to `http://mypage.com/api/vi/settings/:id.json` with params: `"{\"settings\":{\"color\":\"red\"}}"`

But I get:

```
uninitialized constant Setting

{"_json"=>"{\"settings\":{\"color\":\"red\"}}",
 "id"=>"1",
 "format"=>"json",
 "setting"=>{"_json"=>"{\"settings\":{\"color\":\"red\"}}"}}
```

How Should I setup route in that case?

---

My routes:

```
app(development)» rake routes |grep settings
             api_v1_setting GET    /api/v1/settings/:id(.:format)         api/v1/settings#show
                            PATCH  /api/v1/settings/:id(.:format)         api/v1/settings#update                            PUT    /api/v1/settings/:id(.:format)         api/v1/settings#update
```

When I am using non resource route:

`put 'settings/:id' => 'settings#update'`

```
app(development)» rake routes |grep settings
api_v1 PUT    /api/v1/settings/:id(.:format)         api/v1/settings#update
```

I get the same error.

Comment: Paste your error trace.

Comment: Full stack trace: https://gist.github.com/f03f9213c445d95b0f34

Answer (score -2):

you can run rake routes | grep settings to check your routes . 
maybe use should modify your setting rotues  with some namespace like this

```
scope :module => :api do
  constraints :subdomain => /(api|testapi|devapi)/ do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :setting, :only => [:show, :update]
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -2):

You can't use resourceful in this case since you don't have Setting model. You need to use non-resourceful routing.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes

Comment: In that case I get the same error. Check my updated question.